# Transparency in pdfs exports from GIMP 2.10.8

Tags: gimp, pdf, transparency

There is something I was able to do with Gimp 2.8 and not with the 2.10.8 version.
In order to use some stamps in pdfs, I have to create them from scanned documents, possibly where they appear on a white background.
What I do is crop the scanned document to the stamp, apply the commend "color to alpha", then export to pdf to obtain a stamp that can be used on various pdf software with the proper function.

The problem is that with the 2.10.8 version of Gimp, the exported pdf does not retain the transparent background. The same procedure works fine with the 2.8 version.

Any clue? Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Try exporting as PNG instead. PNGs definitely support transparency and you should be able to use them in other software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too ran into this bug in version 2.10.22. Per the bug tracker it should be fixed in version 2.10.24, which is not yet stable at the time of writing this. Here is the link to the bug tracker item.
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/issues/5938